# Membership Security: select one PasswordQuestion  from dropdown menu

Tags: asp.net

Create new user by Membership.
Can I put several questions in a dropdown menu? When I pick up one, then it will be saved into the database aspnet_Memberhip PasswordQuestion field?
Because usually membership will save one question in a text box, I am not sure how the membership framework works.

```
<tr>
                            <td>Question:</td>
                            <td>
                                <%--<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Question" Height="30px" Width="311px" />--%>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Question" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem>What is the city of your birth?</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>What school did you attend for sixth grade?</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>What is your maternal grandmother&#39;s maiden name?</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Where were you when you had your first kiss?</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Who was your childhood hero?</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" ControlToValidate="Question" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Question is required." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Answer:</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Answer" Height="22px" Width="217px" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" ControlToValidate="Answer" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Answer is required." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, you just need to pass the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx)`.Text` to the [CreateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82xx2e62.aspx)-Method. The Question or Answer must not be unique.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.passwordquestion.aspx

Comment: I didn't pass it, just used my code above. Why it is saved to the database automatelly?

Comment: That is because your code is part of a CreateUserWizard (what you haven't mentioned) and you are using `Question` as  ID for the DropDownList. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050609-1.aspx